# Virtual keyboard or onscreen keyboard for QtWidgets applications?

Tags: qt, desktop-application, virtual-keyboard, on-screen-keyboard, qtwidgets

I'm going to deploy the `qtvirtualkeyboard` in my widget-based application like so:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    QLineEdit input(&window);
    input.move(250, 250);
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

But the only issue is that the virtual keyboard input panel hides the underlying widgets and cover them!

How should I achieve this?

Is there any document or solution for widgets-based applications?

Comment: Beware that Qt Virtual Keyboard is available under GNU General Public License, version 3 (and not under LGPL for other modules) -- see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html#licenses-and-attributions). You might need a commercial license...Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the solution!

You just need to call `QGuiApplication::inputMethod()` to get the application-wide Qt input method and then call [`QInputMethod::keyboardRectangle()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#keyboardRectangle-prop) and [`QInputMethod::isVisible()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputmethod.html#visible-prop) to get input method properties then remain a calculation based on your widget position and keyboard coordinate, here is a full-working sample to share:

`lineedit.h`:

```
class LineEdit :public QLineEdit {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    LineEdit(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    LineEdit(const QString&, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

protected:
    bool event(QEvent*) override;

private:
    bool _moved = false;
    int _lastDiff = 0;
};
```

`lineedit.cpp`:

```
LineEdit::LineEdit(QWidget *parent) :QLineEdit(parent) {
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled, true);
    setInputMethodHints(inputMethodHints() | Qt::InputMethodHint::ImhDigitsOnly);
}

LineEdit::LineEdit(const QString& txt, QWidget *parent) : QLineEdit(txt, parent) {
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled, true);
    setInputMethodHints(inputMethodHints() | Qt::InputMethodHint::ImhDigitsOnly);
}

bool LineEdit::event(QEvent* e) {
    const auto keyboard_rect = QGuiApplication::inputMethod()->keyboardRectangle();
    const auto keyboard_visible = QGuiApplication::inputMethod()->isVisible();
    const auto global_y = QWidget::mapToGlobal(rect().topLeft()).y() + height();
    const auto k_global_y = keyboard_rect.topLeft().y();
    const auto diff = k_global_y - global_y;
    const auto need_to_move = diff < 0;

    /* move main widget */
    if (keyboard_visible && !_moved && need_to_move) {
        _moved = true;
        _lastDiff = diff;
        const auto g = parentWidget()->frameGeometry();
        parentWidget()->move(g.x(), g.y() - qAbs(_lastDiff));
    }
    /* roll back */
    if (!keyboard_visible && _moved) {
        _moved = false;
        const auto g = parentWidget()->frameGeometry();
        parentWidget()->move(g.x(), g.y() + qAbs(_lastDiff));
    }
    return QLineEdit::event(e);
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#define W 1024
#define H 768

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow window(nullptr, Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    LineEdit lineedit1(&window);
    lineedit1.move(100, 450);

    LineEdit lineedit2(&window);
    lineedit2.move(100, 100);

    window.resize(W, H);
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

results:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you just need to add this line in   main.cpp

```
qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));
```

and will work Virtual Keyboard in Qtwidgets))
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I did this already and the only issue is that the keyboard in some cases hides the widgets behind it and act as an overlay! here is a demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBET7.gif

Comment: Yes, I solved this question manually, you need to catch the event, and when you open the virtual keyboard, rearrange the window so that they were visible,

Comment: use QStackedWidget

Comment: But as far as I know qtvirtualkeyboard is implemented in QML so where is the keyboard widget to use inside QStackedWidget or to catch event? regards.

Comment: Any idea about this?

Comment: @IMAN4K QT alone cannot fix your interface, you need to do it manually,

Comment: if you do not open to full screen, then this will already be 2 problem ,

Comment: I will open my MainWindow in fullscreen but how could I fix this manually? can you help us in more detail. Regards