# How to move QWidget offscreen on linux?

Tags: c++, qt, x11, qwidget, window-managers

In some cases, we need to move `QWidget` outside the screen coordinate (move it with negative pos), for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57270054/5446734) we need to move our main widget offscreen for the user to see what he/she is typing via `virtual keyboard` but this behavior is not working under X11 platform(tested under `ubuntu 18.04`).

- Is it related to `window manager` or `Qt`?
- What is the solution for this?

Comment: Why not just `hide()` the widget rather than move it "off screen"?

Comment: @JesperJuhl. We show Qt virtual keyboard when user click on input and we need to move the main window off screen to see what we're typing in the input widget, so we can't hide the main window(behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgXCH.gif)

Comment: @JesperJuhl. BTW, I just want exactly the `ALT + Left Button` behavior for window moving